# How to perform server-side validation before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

Form contains input element. Entered value is validated using server callback from blur
event andler.

If wrong value is entered and submit button is pressed, form is submitted with wrong value:
Validate method is not completed but form submit action method is executed.

How to force Validate() method to be completed before form submit method is executed ?

jquery, jqueryUI, ASP .NET MVC2 are used.

```
<form id="Form" class='form-fields' method='post'   action='/Report/Render'>
  <input id='test' name='test' value='test' />
  <input id='_submit' type='submit' value='Show report' />
</form>

    $('#test').bind({
        blur: function (e) {
            if (!Validate(e.target)) {
                cancel(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Update**

As required in BobTodd comment here is validate method:

```
function Validate(elem) {
var i,
  res;
$.ajax('Grid/Validate' );
   {
       data: $("#Form").serializeArray(),
       //async: false,
       type: 'POST',
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           elem.skipBlur = true;
           errorMessage(decodeErrorMessage(jqXHR.responseText === undefined ? '' : jqXHR.responseText,
                      textStatus, errorThrown));
           elem.focus();
           elem.select();
           elem.skipBlur = false;
           elem.ischanged = true;
           res = false;
       },
       success: function (data) {
           elem.ischanged = false;
           for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
               $('#' + data[i].name).val(data[i].value);
           }
           res = true;
       }
   });
return false; //  res;
```

}

**Update2**

All answers suggest to prevent submit method to run if validation is not preformed. This provides very bad user experience: validate takes some time. User shoudl press **two times** in submit button for form to submit. How to allow form to submit using single click ? Maksing Validate() sync method alllws this but i'm not sure is using sync call reasonable solution for this.

Comment: where's the server call back here? Where is the Validate(object) function you've got there?

Comment: @BobTodd: I updated question and added Validate method called in code sample

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rerun the Validate method on form submit and cancel it there.

Look at the jQuery Validate plugin, it supports remove validation methods that work super easy w/ mvc.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

Comment: thank you. jquery validate plugin remote() allows to call server side method before submit. Form contains may input elements validates from server from blur event. How to validate only the element which loses focus if submit button is clicked. Validation updates some fields so calling server for every field is not possible, only changed field needs to be validated. How to implement this ? I updates question.

Comment: You actually don't have to. The plugin is smart enough to only validate fields that have changed since the last validation.

Comment: Two ussues: 1) As shown in code sample, I need to update other fields if validation is OK. For example, after validating product code product name,price and quantity is stock should also be updated. remote() method requires remote validator to return only true on success. How to get list of name/value pairs returned from remote validator ? 2) How to pass all form fields to remote validator? according to remote doc only current field value  is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the submit button until validation is complete.

Comment: In this case user sees active submit button and click it. After that input element blur event disables submit button. Not sure that this prevents submit event since button is already clicked. Anyway this looks like bad user experience: click in submit is ignored, user should click again. It should be better that submit is executed after validation ends successfully. How to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt you be best served binding that jquery to the submit event of the form instead otherwise its just when the user leaves the textbox...

```
$('.form-fields').bind({
        submit: function (e) {
            if (!Validate(e.target)) {
                cancel(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Validate is async method, it returns immediately without waiting result from server. So your code sample always succeeds or always blocks submit depending on the result returned by Validate(). Your sample works if Validate as changed to perform sync call as shown in comments in valudate code in updated answer. I'm not sure if changing Validate to perform sync call is reasonable, jquery docs warn against making syns calls.

Answer (score 0):

When you validate a field, add a `valid` class to the element if it's valid. Then, when submitting the form, simply check if all of the fields have that class :

```
$('#Form').submit(funciton(e){
    $(this).find('input').length == $(this).find('input.valid').length || e.preventDefault();
});
$('#Form input').bind({
    blur: function (e) {
        if(Validate(e.target))
           $(e.target).addClass('valid');
        else  
           $(e.target).removeClass('valid');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code requires user to press two times to submit button to submit form. In first press validate is in progress and submit is always cancelled. I updated question. How to submit form using single click ?